# Delete paragraph from PDF - Java

Tags: java, itext

Greeting,
What is the easiest way to delete text/paragraph from a PDF document. The program takes a PDF document and creates a separate PDF document for each page. In each document I have text from the original that I would like to delete.
I tried a couple of examples but it doesn't work or they use old libraries
I am using the iText 7 library

```
private void processPDF(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfDictionary dict = reader.getPageN(1);
    PdfObject object = dict.getDirectObject(PdfName.CONTENTS);

    if (object instanceof PRStream) {
        PRStream stream = (PRStream) object;
        byte[] data = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
        String dd = new String(data, "UTF8")
                .replace("Hand made software", "");
        stream.setData(dd.getBytes("UTF8"));
        if (dd.contains("Hand made software")) {
            System.out.println("Contains");
        } 
    }

    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();

}


private void processPDF2(String src, String dest) throws InvalidPasswordException, IOException {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Hand made software", "");
    File template = new File(src);
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(template);
    List<PDField> fields = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getFields();
    for (PDField field : fields) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().equals(field.getFullyQualifiedName())) {
                field.setValue(entry.getValue());
                field.setReadOnly(true);
            }
        }
    }
    File out = new File(dest);
    document.save(out);
    document.close();
}
```

I want to delete line "Hand made software"

Comment: Note: I removed the [tag:javafx] tag because the question doesn't really involve JavaFX, even if you're using it as part of your real application.

Comment: Hand made software is  nonsense in my pdf. It is plain text

Answer (score 0):

You can make it easy iterating through the PDF elements. First create a PDF reader and writter that will read the template located on src string path.

```
File template = new File(src);
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(template);

File out = new File(dest);
PdfWritter writter = new PdfWritter(out);
```

Then create a Document object by firstly creating a PdfDocument:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader, writter);
Document document = new Document(pdf);
```

Last iterate through the elements of the pdf document until "Hand made software" line is found:

```
for (int i = 0; i < document.getRoots().size(); i++) {
     if (document.getRoots().get(i) instanceof Paragraph) { //iterate only through paragraphs
         Paragraph paragraph = (Paragraph) document.getRoots().get(i);
         if(paragraph.getText().equals("Hand made software")){ //if the paragraph equals to the string to be removed, remove from the document
             document.getRoots().remove(i);
             i--;
         }
     }
}
```

Finally close de document to save the changes

```
document.close();
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I just ask what library you use for Document. Whichever library I use getRoots() cannot be found

Comment: com.itextpdf.layout, com.apache.poi,  org.w3c.dom . Still I can't use .getRoots()

Comment: Hi, I have used itext classes:

import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;

Comment: What version of iText are you using?